# Can I simplify this approach to installing and exporting a CMake-based project?

Tags: c++, cmake, package, buildconfiguration

<sub>Note: Re-asking a poorly-written earlier question.</sub>

How should a package/library developer, using CMake, allow for their package to be effectively installed on a system, as well as easily integrated/used in another CMake-based project?

According to the oft-linked-to [talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bsXLMQ6WgIk) by Daniel Pfeiffer (slides [here](https://github.com/boostcon/cppnow_presentations_2017)), this is an example of how it's done:

In `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
find_package(Bar 2.0 REQUIRED)
add_library(Foo ...)
target_link_libraries(Foo PRIVATE Bar::Bar)

install(TARGETS Foo EXPORT FooTargets
    LIBRARY DESTINATION lib
    ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib
    RUNTIME DESTINATION bin
    INCLUDES DESTINATION include
)

install(EXPORT FooTargets
    FILE FooTargets.cmake
    NAMESPACE Foo::
    DESTINATION lib/cmake/Foo
)
```

in a second file (which?):

```
include(CMakePackageConfigHelpers)
write_basic_package_version_file("FooConfigVersion.cmake"
    VERSION ${Foo_VERSION}
    COMPATIBILITY SameMajorVersion
)
install(FILES "FooConfig.cmake" "FooConfigVersion.cmake"
    DESTINATION lib/cmake/Foo
)
```

in a third file (which?):

```
include(CMakeFindDependencyMacro)
find_dependency(Bar 2.0)
include("${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/FooTargets.cmake")
```

So, we have:

- At least four different CMake files (`CMakeLists.txt`, `FooTargets.cmake`, `FooConfig.cmake`, `FooConfigVersion.cmake`)
- ... more than one of which is generated, but more than one is written by hand
- ... and which also include each other
- ... and whose names do not make it clearer which does what
- ... with some, but not all of them, getting installed.

I keep getting confused and mixed-up about this. Pfeifer says "I wish this were easier; but at least it's straightforward" - it's not really that straightforward.

Questions:

- Can this be simplified somehow?
- If not, why are each of these files important to have?
- Can't some more of the files be auto-generated with less commands/scripts/files generated dynamically?

Comment: I tried to do it myself and I ended up with exactly the same configuration : export targets, include targets in a config.cmake file. And it also took me a lot of instructions.

Comment: @ArneJ: 1. But did you need four (or more) files as well? 2. What about automating this whole thing, at least?

Comment: Well in source at least 2 files : one CMakeLists.txt and one config.cmake.in . Then I have CMake generate myptoject-config.cmake (with a function similar to write_basic_package_version_file(), but for config files). The installed files I have are the exported targets, config and version files, correct ! So your setup seems quite ok to me, and I did mine more than a year ago. Maybe just find out if you can also reuse one config.cmake.in

Comment: @ArneJ: Perhaps you should make that comment into an answer.

Answer (score 0):

In conclusion : when I tried to do this about a year ago, I had a very similar setup.

In source at least 2 files : one CMakeLists.txt and one config.cmake.in . Then I have CMake generate myproject-config.cmake with configure_package_config_file().

In installed files I also had the exported targets, config and version files.

As a suggestion, find out if you can also reuse one config.cmake.in using configure_package_config_file().

Comment: 1. If this is a FOSS project - can you link to it? 2. Did you also need to repeat yourself, e.g. by listing dependencies like in my example? 3. Why do we need both a config file and a version file? Can't they both be in the same file?